# VirtualBox and AltGr not working

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, alt, altgr

Im connecting from a windows 7 PC to another windows 7 PC using Teamviewer 10. On the remote Windows 7 I have a VirtualBox running Ubuntu 16. When working in the remote VB the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key appear not to work properly. For instance `[` (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>), and `{` (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>) does not work at all (no character appears after pressing the key combination), <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> results in 
 `3` (not expected `£`), while strangely `$` works.
Any suggestions ? 
I took a look of the post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/710091/how-to-use-the-alt-key-in-a-virtual-box-guest-session) but in vain.

I should say it works fine when communicating to the remote Windows 7 (that hosts the VB). And when connecting via Teamviewer from another PC running GalliumOS the same thing (work on remote Windows, not in the VB).

Comment: (sounds like a teamviewer 10 bug to me)

Comment: Does nix recognise AltGr as a distinct key? Mac doesn't, & I always thought it was distinctly a Windows thing. Did you try ctrl/alt/[key] instead?

Comment: Yes tried these combinations with no luck. Hate it - need to copy-paste those characters from elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Are you using a non-English keyboard? I just realised none of those characters require much more than the Shift key on UK or US. [ has its own key, as does ] { & } are the same [ ] keys, just shifted. £ is Shift/3 on UK, alt/3 on US with # being the opposite for each.